# Can a double not be less than one, so is .027412133 not able to be stored as a double?

Tags: c#, math

So I have two simple math lines in a code. I am trying to find out the distance of a shot. I have the degrees of the shot which gets converted into radians and than the radians gets converted into distance. My radians formula should be radians = degrees * PI / 180.0 which seems to be correct and the distance formula should be distance = velocity^2 * sin(2*radians) / 32.2  The distance formula I broke down on multiple lines to try to render the issue and it seems that when I go to sin my radians after multiplying it by 2 it get sets the value of radians to 1 instead of .027412133.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double radians = 0.0;
        double degrees = 45.0;
        double velocity = 250.0;
        double distance = 0.0;

        radians = (degrees * Math.PI) / 180.0;
        velocity = Math.Pow(velocity, velocity);
        radians = 2 * radians;
        radians = Math.Sin(radians);
        Console.WriteLine(radians);
        distance = velocity * radians / 32.2;
        Console.WriteLine(distance);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Doubles can, of course, be smaller than 1. The problem is somewhere else...

Comment: I figured it could be less than 1 any idea why my Math.Sin(radians) gets the value of 1?

Comment: If degrees is 45 and you double it to get 90 then the sin of 90 degrees is 1, why would it be less than 1?

Comment: Ya I'M sorry for this post everything checks out.

Comment: Question is a math problem, rather than a programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SteveO'Connor pointed out, 1 **is** the right answer:

```
double radians = 0.0d;
double degrees = 45.0d;

radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180.0d;
radians = 2.00d * radians;
Console.WriteLine(radians * 180 / Math.PI); 

//returns 90, so sin(radians) == sin(90) which = 1
```

**BTW:** Double has a range of: ±5.0 × 10e−324 to ±1.7 × 10e308

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

> The double-precision binary floating-point exponent is encoded using
>   an offset-binary representation, with the zero offset being 1023; also
>   known as exponent bias in the IEEE 754 standard. Examples of such
>   representations would be:
>
> Emin (1) = −1022
>
> E (50) = −973
>
> Emax (2046) = 1023

Double precision floating point numbers use a fixed number of digits for fraction and exponent, both of which can represent negative numbers.